# primefaces height of layoutunits and height of page

Tags: css, jsf, primefaces

I trying to use p:layout (fullpage=false).But changing the height of east,west and center units.
e.g.

```
    <p:layout fullPage="false">

    <p:layoutUnit position="north" size="100" header="Top"
        resizable="true" closable="true" collapsible="true">
    </p:layoutUnit>

    <p:layoutUnit style="height:auto !important;" position="west" size="200" header="Left"
        resizable="true" closable="true" collapsible="true">
        <div style="width:100%;height:400px;background-color:gray;"></div>

    </p:layoutUnit>

    <p:layoutUnit style="height:auto !important;" position="east" size="200" header="Right"
        resizable="true" closable="true" collapsible="true" effect="drop">
        <div style="width:100%;height:400px;background-color:gray;"></div>
    </p:layoutUnit>

    <p:layoutUnit position="center">
    //page code
</p:layoutUnit>

</p:layout>
```

east and west heights:400px.But When viewing in the browser,height of units 400px but height of wrapper div 833px(I check with chrome-inspect element).so page can going down.I want the size of page should be changed according to the context(east/west/center).How can I do that correctly?How to I get rid of spontaneous space?thanks in advance.
[image]

Comment: do you have screenshots? I fail to understand the issue. And the center having a different height then its west and east 'partners' is afaik impossible.

Comment: I updated.The output of the code there.

Comment: What if fullPage is removed?  Is the default fullPage then?

Comment: defaul fullPage=false.therefore, no change :/